# Display 404 page in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I created new website using `Codeigniter`. What puzzled me was when I transferred it to my web server, every page displayed `404` page....

Here's the twist, when I changed my controllers like from `home` to `Home`, it will now display correctly.

Can someone tell me why this happened? Is this fine? Do I have to access every pages like `example.com/Home` or `example.com/home`?

Thanks.

Comment: could you check your path settings ```application/controllers/main.php
application/controllers/page1.php
application/views/main.php
application/views/page1.php```

Comment: What should I do? Actually, I already capitalize all the first letters of my controllers, models, and views.

Comment: Why this thing happened? In my local computer, I just use the small caps for my controllers, models, and views.

Answer (score 0):

In Codeigniter version 3 and above, the controller name should start with a capital letter. that's why when you rename your controller from `home` to `Home`, it's started working.

The Windows os will treat the file names as case insensitive, but Linus is case sensitive. so this might be the reason it worked in local windows development environment.